# Java - NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Hi im new to java and am getting the error code -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Code -

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed to make Scanner available

class loan
{
    public static void main (String [] a)
    {
        askQuestions();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    public static void askQuestions ()
    {
        float loantaken;
        float loanpaid;
        double d = 7;
    
        loantaken = Loan_Taken();
        loanpaid = Loan_Paid();
    
        float subtraction = (loantaken-loanpaid);
        double d2 = ((((d/100)*subtraction)+subtraction)*10);
        int value = (int)d2;
        float finalvalue = (float)value/10;
     
        System.out.println("The new amount owed is (in pounds) " + finalvalue);
        return;
    }

    public static Float Loan_Taken()
    {
        float taken;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("Amount of loan taken at the start of the year :");
        taken = scanner.nextFloat();
    
        return taken;
    }

    public static Float Loan_Paid()
    {
        float paid;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("Amount of loan paid off this year :");
        paid = scanner.nextFloat();
    
        return paid;
    }



}
```

Im not sure on how to fix this. I have started by using jupyter hub which doesnt require you to format it in such a way so im confused on how to format it correctly.

Comment: what line throws that Exception? Also, Java and JavaScript aren't the same. That's the first thing you should know

Comment: im getting "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496)
 at loan.Loan_Taken(loan.java:35)
 at loan.askQuestions(loan.java:17)
 at loan.main(loan.java:7)"

Comment: that should be in your question. Do you know what that means, how to read it?

Comment: You keep creating new Scanner objects; you don't need to. Do you ever close any of them? (You should not, until you end the program. If you close the scanner, you close System.in, and it can't be reopened easily.)

Comment: Java naming conventions do not use underscores except in constants. Classes use CamelCase and start with an upper case letter; methods and variables use camelCase, starting with a lower case letter (loanTaken()).

Comment: I think the errors are occuring due to the scanners? not sure if im analysing the error correctly. When i try this code in eclipse ide it works however when i use it with notepad and cmd i get an error "could not find main class loan" and when i run it on an online java compiler i get the no element exception error im confused.

Comment: What do you mean by notepad and cmd? Please show us the exact command line you are using to start the program.

Comment: PS C:\users\hs\desktop> javac loan.java
PS C:\users\hs\desktop> java loan
Error: Could not find or load main class loan